# How to define/set a model for Ember's partial?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the [Ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/), the partial seem to magically get author's firstname and lastname attributes.

But it is failing for my try, [see my jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/235/edit) where I have two models: Organization (with "name" and "description") and Member (with "name"). Organizations is displayed successfully, but I'm failing to display the Members.

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="organization">
      ...
      {{ partial "member" }}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="_member">
     Here are the Members:
     <ul>
      {{#each member}}
        <li>{{member.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
     </ul>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it here: http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/239/edit

Let me know if you have any questions about how it works.

Edward

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Edward said as he didn't have time to complete his answer:

I shouldn't use a partial in this case. The [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/) says that *`{{partial}}` does not change context or scope. It simply drops the given template into place with the current scope.* This means there is no route jumping for partials. So **partials do not have routes**, like the `App.Router.map ... this.resource()...` defined.

This is a simplified version of [Edward's jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/243/edit), taking out the unnecessary partial.

The key to displaying both the org model and the member model

```
  Here are the Orgs:
  <ul>
  {{#each model}}
    <li>{{name}} - {{description}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>

  Here are the Members:
  {{#each member in members}}
    <li>{{member.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
```

is in the controller:

```
App.OrganizationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Org.find();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('members', App.Member.find());
  }
});
```